# VHDL with select when error

Tags: vhdl

VHDL is the worst designed language with the worst syntax that I have ever encountered.
Why does this with-select-when code give me an error?:

```
  library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity mux48 is
port(
   mux48dv0:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   mux48dv1:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   mux48dv2:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   mux48dv3:in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
   mux48sv:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   mux48ov:out std_logic_vector(7 downto 0)
);
end mux48;

architectre mux48_df of mux48 is
begin
    with mux48sv select
    mux48ov <= mux48dv0 when "0000",
        <= mux48dv1 when "0001",
        <= mux48dv2 when "0010",
        <= mux48dv3 when "0011",
        <= mux48dv0 when "0100",
        <= mux48dv1 when "0101",
        <= mux48dv2 when "0110",
        <= mux48dv3 when "0111",
        <= mux48dv0 when "1000",
        <= mux48dv1 when "1001",
        <= mux48dv2 when "1010",
        <= mux48dv3 when "1011",
        <= mux48dv0 when "1100",
        <= mux48dv1 when "1101",
        <= mux48dv2 when "1110",
        <= mux48dv3 when "1111";
end mux48_df;
```

error:

```
** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.3/Lab3/mux48.vhd(15): near "architectre": syntax error
```

Comment: VHDL has plenty of problems and quirks, but it is the best language available in its field when used correctly. You aren't going to encourage good answers to your questions by harshly and preemptively critisizing a language you are just barely learning.

Comment: So which language tolerates spelling errors in keywords?

Comment: It seems odd to specify a 16:1 mux and call it a Mux4.  If you're doing byte lane steering and the reordering is regular you could create a select (1 downto 0) signal and assign it so, `mux48sel <= mux48sv(3 downto 2) xor (muxsv(1 downto 0);`  You can do this bitwise if the reordering relates to bits.

Comment: It isn't a 16:1 mux; it's a 4:1 MUX with 12 useless extra lines of code because he's choosing to fight VHDL instead of use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several syntax errors: The assignment should look like

```
with mux48sv select
   mux48ov <= mux48dv0 when "0000",
              mux48dv1 when "0001",
              ...
              mux48dv3 when others;
```